# Windows BlockInput function is not working

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, input

Why `BlockInput` isn't working

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winable.h>
int main() {
    BlockInput(true);
    Sleep(10000);
    return 0;
}
```

and it simply doesn't block anything!
I can still do everything like I haven't even done that.
what I also find weird is that [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646290%28v=vs.85%29) sais that it should be declared in `winuser.h` and it is in `Winable.h` + I thought that `winable.h` is in `windows.h` but It's not, I had to include it seperatly >_>

If it helps my IDE is:
Code::Blocks 10.05 MinGW

EDIT: Actually I did the `GetLastError()` and it prints error 5 `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`
How may I get the access?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run your code as an administrator. Right-click on the executable and click 'run as Administrator'.