# Can you turn peripherals off in WINAPI?

Tags: winapi

Is there any function in WINAPI that disables or turns off peripherals? For example

```
#include <Windows.h>
int main()
{
TurnMouseOff(); // what to use here 
Sleep(1000);
TurnMouseOn(); // what to use here
}
```

or any function like MouseMovement(true) for enabled / MouseMovement(false) for disabled?

Comment: Unlikely. Why would you want to do this.

Comment: Because I want to be able to turn my mouse off without manually removing its cable.

Comment: Why not stop touching the mouse?

Comment: It's possible indeed :P But I was looking for something more automated

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is possible to simulate a hardware unplug event (might not be possible for PS/2 devices). If you want to go down this route you would have to look at the tests performed by [WLK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Hardware_Certification_Kit)/[WHQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHQL_Testing) certification. You could try [IOCTL_INTERNAL_USB_CYCLE_PORT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/usbioctl/ni-usbioctl-ioctl_internal_usb_cycle_port) but using SetupAPI to disable the driver might be a better approach.

If you only care about the mouse and keyboard you can create [low level hooks](http://SetWindowsHookEx) and just eat all the input messages.

Comment: After days trying to get it right, I found out BlockInput actually worked, but I had to run it as an administrator (facepalm)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046393/windows-blockinput-function-is-not-working